# GET input as PHP array

Tags: php, html, forms

I have my HTML input as

```
<input type="number" name="no_pi" id="no_pi" class="form-control" placeholder="Number of Pieces">
```

and other two inputs as

```
<input type="number" name="ht" id="ht" placeholder="Height of Package" class="form-control">
<input type="number" name="bd" id="bd" placeholder="Breadth of Package" class="form-control">
```

I want to user input `3` in number of pieces field, then input `20, 20, 30` in weight and `10, 10, 20` in breadth fields.

PHP will then do calculations with every `20, 10` and then next pair and so on `x` number of times as assigned in the number of pieces field.

PS: Array defined above is example if user input 5 in number of pieces then both arrays should be of 5 values and PHP will do calculations of those 5 pairs.

Any idea how to achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and [array_map](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to achieve this.

```
function inputToArray(string $string)
{
    $string = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $string);
    $string = trim($string, ",");
    $array = array_map('intval', explode(',', $string));
    return $array;
}

$no_of_pieces = (int)$_POST['no_pi'];
$ht = $_POST['ht']; //make sure it is in format 1,2,3,4,.....
$ht = inputToArray($ht); //array(20,30,10)
$bd = $_POST['bd']; //make sure it is in format 1,2,3,4,.....
$bd = inputToArray($bd); // array(10,20,30)

if ((count($ht) === count($bd)) && (count($bd) === $no_of_pieces)) {
    for ($piece = 0; $piece < $no_of_pieces; $piece++) {
        $areaOfPiece = $ht[$piece] * $bd[$piece];
        echo $areaOfPiece;
    }
} else {
    echo "Number of inputs does not match";
}
```